# Cheerio how to get the tag name of one element

Tags: node.js, typescript, cheerio, tagname

I am using Cheerio to **scrape** one web site, i need to know the tag name of the element , but according to Cheerio API there is not any property that retrieve that.
My snippet of code :

```
const links = $("body").find("path...");
link.each((i,elem)=>{
   elem.name;
});
```

i am using typescript in NodeJs,Typescript throws an error saying that this property does not even exist.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer
$(element).get(0).tagName

Thanks